# SSIS: trying to convert a flat file with 1 column but has 2 types of data into a table with 2 columns

Tags: sql, database, ssis, ssms-2014

I am using `SSIS` and am trying to convert a flat file that has a column for `SSN` and `RN` to a table that has 2 columns, one for `SSN` which is `varchar(9)` and the other for `RN` which is `varchar(2)`.
 How do I split the flat file up into the 2 separate columns?

Comment: what is the flat file look like in your case? is that delimited or just raw file?

Comment: It's a raw txt file

Comment: Can you add a part of the raw file and explain what you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I was trying to do a cast and i switched it to a substring. I created one expression that would start at the first character and pull 9 characters. I then created a second expression that would start at character 10 and pull 2 characters. Once that was done, I did a data conversion to switch them to a string.

```
SUBSTRING([SSN      RN],1,9)
SUBSTRING([SSN      RN],10,2)
```

The job was successful and was imported into the table as 2 separate columns